# How to use Vuetify in Laravel 9 Vue SPA?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3, single-page-application

I just wanted to add vuetify to my app, but after installing packages and setting up `resources\js\app.js` I have error at the runtime:

```
Uncaught TypeError: vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a is undefined
```

This is my `resources\js\app.js`

```
import Alpine from 'alpinejs';
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import router from './router'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import UserName from './components/layout/UserName.vue'
import NavigationLinks from './components/layout/NavigationLinks.vue'

require('./bootstrap');

createApp({
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    components: {
        UserName,
        NavigationLinks,
    }
})
.use(createPinia())
.use(router)
.use(Vuetify)
.mount('#app')

window.Alpine = Alpine;
Alpine.start();
```

In docs I see `import Vue from 'vue'` But it getting me an error, I use `createApp`
What am I doing wrong?
Vue 3, Vuetify 2.6, Laravel 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe because [Vuetify  doesn't suport Vue3](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/) yet